# O que é "Princípio da Inversão de Dependência" (DIP)?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern, solid

Estou conhecendo agora o principio **SOLID**:

- **S**    Single Responsabilty Principle
- **O**    Open/Closed
- **L**    Liskov Substitution Principle
- **I**    Interface Segregation
- **D**    Dependency Inversion  Principle

Entretanto não consegui entender o ultimo o Principio de Inversão de Dependência!
O que ele é e quando devo usa-lo?
Gostaria de um exemplo simples em linguagem java de seu uso.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## O que é *Dependency Inversion Principle*?

O *Princípio da Inversão de Dependência* procura manter o foco da tarefa de design no negócio, deixando este design independente ou desacoplado do componente que vai executar as tarefas de baixo nível que não fazem parte da modelagem do negócio.

Em respeito a este princípio, em vez de desenvolver o componente de baixo nível e a partir dele orientar o desenvolvimento do componente de alto nível, você define como vai ser a interação entre estes componentes (sempre privilegiando as necessidades de design do componente de alto nível), e daí o componente de baixo nível tem que ser desenvolvido respeitando esta definição de interação com o componente de alto nível.

## Exemplo - cotações da bolsa de valores

Digamos que você precise desenvolver uma tela que mostre para o usuário, um operador da bolsa de valores, a cotação atual de cada ativo que ele possui em carteira.

O operador quer que a tela seja atualizada cada vez que a cotação de um ativo mudar, pois ele quer saber o total por ativo e o total na carteira quase em tempo real.

O operador vai pagar por um serviço web de cotação em tempo real e o seu software deve utilizar este serviço.

Você precisa fazer um componente que se conecte a este serviço, e o serviço vai notificar o seu componente todas as vezes que um papel mudar de valor, e então o componente pode atualizar a carteira, promovendo a atualização da tela.

A maneira mais simplória de desenvolver este software seria implementar primeiro o componente que se conecta com o serviço (chamado aqui de *ConectorBolsa*), ver como ele ficou e daí implementar a atualização da carteira de acordo com as necessidades do *ConectorBolsa*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na solução acima, **o componente de alto nível depende do componente de baixo nível**.

Já a maneira de fazer isso respeitando o *Princípio da Inversão de Dependência* seria você definir como deve ser a interação entre os componentes, e daí ambos os componentes são desenvolvidos respeitando esta definição de interação entre eles.

A esta "definição de interação" damos o nome de "abstração". Dizemos que você criou uma **abstração entre os componentes**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Cada componente não precisa saber como o outro foi implementado, e o foco do design é na solução de negócio e não nos detalhes de como é feita a conexão com o serviço de cotações.

## Interfaces

A maneira mais comum de fazer isso em Java é declarando uma interface que determina como o componente de atualização de carteira gostaria de consumir um serviço de cotação, e então o componente que se conecta ao serviço de cotação implementa esta interface.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Antes, o componente de alto nível dependia do componente de baixo nível mas agora, com a solução acima, o componente de baixo nível é que depende de uma interface definida pelas diretrizes de negócio - dizemos então que houve uma **inversão de dependência**.

## Capacidade de substituir o componente no futuro?

Este é o motivo mais pífio para se respeitar o princípio.

O grande benefício do princípio é manter o foco do design nas necessidades do negócio em vez de depender dos detalhes de implementação e necessidades dos objetos de mais baixo nível.

O respeito ao princípio também deve resultar em componentes mais reutilizáveis e que não precisam mudar apenas para acompanhar as mudanças necessárias em outro componente (os componentes podem mudar de maneira independente um do outro).

Por fim, um efeito colateral muito positivo de o componente de negócio não estar mais acoplado ao componente de baixo nível, é que o componente de baixo nível pode ser substituído por um dublê (vulgo "mock") durante os testes automatizados.

Comment: Muito Obrigado cara!

Answer (score 3):

Podemos considerar as classes de baixo nível as classes que implementam as operações básicas e primárias(acesso ao disco , protocolos de rede) e classes de alto nível(fluxos de negócios).

Uma maneira natural de implementação de tais estruturas seria escrever as classes de baixo nível e uma vez que as tiver escrito começasse a escrever as de alto nível. Como as classes de alto nível são definidas em outros termos este parece ser o caminho mais lógico

Mas este não é um design flexível . O que acontece se precisar substituir uma classe de baixo nível? Teria que reescrever toda a sua classe de alto nível? Uma é dependente da outra, por este motivo criou-se a *DIP*.

Como pode ver pelo exemplo, assim reformulando o conceito dessa dependência:

```
interface IWorker 
{
  public void work();
}
class Worker implements IWorker
{
  public void work() 
  {
    // ....working
  }
}
class SuperWorker  implements IWorker
{
   public void work() 
   {
    //.... working much more
   }
}
class Manager 
{
   IWorker worker;

   public void setWorker(IWorker w) 
   {
      worker = w;
   }

  public void manage() 
  {
    worker.work();
  }
}
```

Sugiro a você o link: [DIP - Example](http://www.oodesign.com/dependency-inversion-principle.html)

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção , cara. Mas antes de fazer essa pergunta eu já tinha lido esse link! Você não poderia editar sua resposta de modo que qualquer leigo como eu pudesse entender o conceito?

Comment: Pior que é o mais explicado que eu conheço, é uma questão complexa, mas nada mais é que e burlar a dependência que o alto nível teria do baixo nível

Comment: É esse o problema, você limitou o conceito a 2 simples termos que servem para exemplificar.