# O que são os princípios SOLID?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software, solid, princípios-de-programação

Ultimamente, tenho ouvido falar bastante no termo mas para mim nunca está claro se é um *design pattern* ou uma boa prática em orientação a objetos. Talvez seja uma pergunta muito ampla, mas por que SOLID é útil e quando devemos utilizá-lo?

Em particular o que é o *S - Single Responsibility Principle* (Princípio da Responsabilidade Única)?

Comment: [O que é e como se usa o SRP?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/91)

Comment: [O que é Princípio da Inversão de Dependência (*Dependency Inversion Principle*)](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101552)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

SOLID é um princípio de programação associado com a orientação a objeto. Portanto é uma regra que se recomenda seguir. Alguns vão chamar de boa prática. Na verdade são conceitos bem interessantes para aprender e saber porque existem, que problemas eles resolvem e principalmente quando usar. A pior coisa que pode fazer com ele é usar sempre. O correto é usar sempre que necessário, quando vai trazer mais benefícios que malefícios. SOLID deve ser uma ferramenta, não o objetivo, como muita gente faz.

Ele é útil para organizar aplicações **complexas** que precisam de **muita manutenção**, que lidam com bastante **incerteza** e que atende muitas **expectativas diferentes**.

Em geral, só se sabe mesmo quando é útil ou não com muita experiência e entendimento profundo de tudo que o circunda. Como isso raramente ocorre, as pessoas ou deixam pra lá totalmente ou passam adotar em tudo o que faz sem ter um critério.

Alguns princípios são mais importantes que outros. Mas quem é muito fã de SOLID acha que todos devem ser usados igualmente.

É comum ocorrer que para lidar com a complexidade ele faz o código ficar ainda mais complexo. Claro que existem vantagens também.

É um acrônimo dos 5 princípios que ajuda você lembrar deles quando estiver arquitetando uma aplicação.

- [**S**ingle responsibility principle](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/101)

  A classe deve ter uma responsabilidade única, não deve fazer mais do que o necessário. O nome deve indicar claramente o que faz para indicar a sua função única. Vale para outras entidades também
- [**O**pen/closed principle](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15645/101)

  As entidades do software deve ser abertas para extensão, mas fechadas para modificação. Assim, facilita a manutenção e evita conflitos entre versões
- [**L**iskov substitution principle](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101)

  Objetos no programa podem ser substituídos por instâncias de seus subtipos sem afetar a coerência da aplicação, portanto o subtipo não pode ter atividades, seja no contrato, seja na implementação, que são incompatíveis com o supertipo
- [**I**nterface segregation principle](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101)

  As interfaces devem indicar o mínimo possível ao invés de fazer tudo o que é possível. Mais interfaces é melhor que interfaces maiores. É quase a mesma coisa da responsabilidade única aplicada para a interface
- [**D**ependency inversion principle](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101552/101)

  O código deve depender de abstrações e não de concretudes. Como algo funciona deve ser definido pelo objeto e não pelo contrato usado. Então é melhor usar interfaces como parâmetros e receber objetos que a implementam como argumento

[Leitura complementar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/336319/101).
[image: Tabela com cada um dos princípios]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).