# Todos atributos herdados devem ser usados?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software, herança, uml, diagrama

Estou construindo um diagrama de classes, onde diversas classes possuem 3 atributos iguais, sendo que uma ou outra classe possui apenas 2 desses atributos. Então pensei em criar uma classe pai com todos esses atributos que se repetem, e criar diversas filhas.

Nestas poucas classes que não utilizem os 3 atributos que se repetem na maioria das outras classes, há problemas em eu não utilizar 2 destes atributos? Ou isto é incorreto?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

Isto é incorreto, porque certamente viola o [princípio de substituição de Liskov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Na verdade parece que não entendeu para que serve a herança. Não é para eliminar repetições, no máximo é para ter um [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101), que é diferente de não repetir.

Em primeiro lugar, se for para eliminar repetição deve usar composição e não herança. Herança só deve ser usada quando há uma relação de ***ser um***, ou seja, [a classe derivada deve ser obrigatoriamente a mesma coisa que a classe base com algo a mais. Não deve ter nada a menos, não deve ter nada diferente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101). A herança no máximo elimina repetição como efeito secundário.

Mesmo a composição é de se pensar se deveria fazer dessa forma, provavelmente deveria fazer uma [segregação de interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178718/101), inclusive porque provavelmente está juntando coisas não relacionadas de fato.

Isso é o ideal. O pragmático sabe quando violar tudo e obter mais benefícios que malefícios.