# Uso de interfaces em classes do domínio?

Tags: c#, .net, arquitetura-de-software, interface, solid

O analista do projeto em que estou trabalhando como programador C# defende energicamente o conceito de SOLID em desenvolvimento. E diz que um dos requisitos para utilizá-lo é ter interfaces para tudo. Inclusive para as classes POCO do domínio.

Como sabem o que geralmente é chamado de domínio (no desenvolvimento em camadas) é onde colocamos os objetos que representam as entidades do banco de dados. Então temos lá uma classe `Pessoa`, `Cliente`, `Produto`, etc.

Não tem nem 1 ano que estou estudando .NET então sou programador júnior. Mas me parece que utilizar interfaces aqui não traz vantagem nenhuma. Só aumenta o código e o esforço de desenvolvimento.

O que vocês acham? Faz sentido ter coisas como a da imagem a seguir? Esclarecendo que nosso banco de dados tem mais de 60 tabelas (temos mais de 70 classes para representar esse banco de dados) e todos com sua respectiva interface. Se como eu também acham desnecessário, que argumentos eu poderia levar ao analista para convencê-lo?

[image: código]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

É um belo ponto pra discussão esse.. vou abrir a discussão com essa resposta.
O objetivo de uma interface é definir um contrato através do qual dois componentes (classes, projetos, serviços, etc) irão se comunicar.
Ok, nem vamos entrar no mérito das vantagens e desvantagens agora, vamos só pensar no propósito: definir um contrato.

Pois bem, isso serve por exemplo para o serviço A, desenvolvido em qualquer plataforma/linguagem se comunique, por exemplo usando usando o clássico *stack* `HTML/SOAP`, com o serviço B, também desenvolvido em qualquer plataforma/linguagem. Aliás, podemos "entender" os protocolos como uma interface, se olharmos para sua propósito, que é um contrato comum, mas vamos voltar ao assunto dos serviços...

Para evitar que o serviço A mande uma bolinha e serviço B espere um quadradinho, definimos uma interface, por exemplo dizendo "A invoca o método `Obter`, passando uma `string` que não pode ser nula de com tamanho máximo de 10, e B deve devolver uma `string` que pode ser nula, como tamanho máximo de 100". Pronto, temos uma interface. Algo como:

```
interface IExemplo {
   string Obter(string valor);
}
```

Isso é muito bom e acredito que ninguém discorde do benefício de usar um contrato. Podemos pensar em vários benefícios do uso das interfaces:

- Abstrair a implementação. Para o serviço "A", não importa como (plataforma, linguagem, etc) foi implementado o serviço "B", desde que ele respeite o contrato;
- Para testar é muito mais simples tomar como referência uma interface;
- Podemos usar a inversão de dependência, entre outras coisas.

Ah, antes aprofundar a discussão, vamos ver o que o princípio da segregação por interfaces do S.O.L.I.D nos diz:

> A client should never be forced to implement an interface that it doesn't use or clients shouldn't be forced to depend on methods they do not use.

Ou em bom e claro português:

> Um cliente nunca deve ser forçado a implementar uma interface que não usa ou os clientes não devem ser obrigados a depender de métodos que não usam.

Ah, referências no bom e velho Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)

O princípio "I" está querendo dizer que é melhor criar interfaces específicas do que uma geral que o cliente não vai utilizar completamente. E claro, criar interfaces para desacoplar o cliente da implementação. Veja que não está escrito "usar interfaces em todo lugar"...

Agora vamos focar no seu objeto POCO. Um objeto de modelo, para simplesmente transportar dados não requer métodos, basta ter atributos. Quem adiciona métodos é seu *Framework* de acesso a dados, seja uma biblioteca um o *ORM*. Portanto, aqui o desacoplamento me parece ser mais do ponto de vista dos métodos ou do seu repositório, que pode ser um BD qualquer, um sistema de arquivos, ou qualquer coisa que guarde a sua informação.

Se vc usar um *ORM* (`Entity Framework`, `NHibernate`, etc), a abstração do repositório já será obtida, concorda?

Agora vamos pensar na manutenção e refatoração, outros pontos importantes para o S.O.L.I.D. Se no serviço que usei como exemplo houver uma mudança da regra de negócio no método `Obter`. Se você alterar o serviço B, na implementação do método `Obter`, nada precisa ser mudado na interface nem no serviço A. Ótimo!!!!

Agora se algo mudar na sua na tabela do banco?
Você tem que alterar a interface em primeiro lugar, depois a classe, e obviamente seu cliente. Não tivemos o benefício da interface aqui, concorda?

Outra coisa, numa classe POCO sem métodos, a inversão de dependência me parece sem sentido também, tirando um Mock é claro, mas só de atributos?

No caso de métodos faz sentido, eu cliente, por uma razão qualquer, quero dizer como e quem irá implementar o comportamento. Aí sim isso me beneficio da interface para fazer um Mock ou um teste.

Por isso, **na minha humilde opinião**, me parece que o local onde melhor se aplica a interface é na classe que irá implementar as operações do repositório, sua DAC (*Data Access Layer*), seu ORM, ou qualquer coisa sim, mas não na classe POCO em si, isso pensando que eu possa usar inversão de dependência para direcionar um teste com dados mockados, ou ainda dizer qual repositório desejo usar.
Portanto, assumir que qualquer comunicação seja feita por interfaces indiscriminadamente, não me parece uma boa abordagem, melhor ver onde realmente se aplica, e isso não fere os princípios do S.O.L.I.D. Penso que as classe POCO não necessitem de interfaces, novamente, **na minha humilde opinião**, respondendo sua pergunta.

Uma última coisa: se usar um template, um T4, um gerador de código que gere classes/interfaces quando você mudar o banco ou vice-versa, mesmo que não faça totalmente sentido usar as interfaces com as classes POCO, pelo menos a parte de manutenção serão simplificada, reduzindo o esforço de escrever código, o que ainda não me convence de usar as interfaces com classes POCO.

Aguardo outras opiniões, concordando ou discordando :-)

Comment: Seguindo o que colocaste, eu achei desnecessário a implementação da interface. Ao que me parece, a classe não é bem um POCO, porque nela está, além da implementação dos campos da tabela, estão os métodos de acesso. Acho que uma abstração da camada de negocios seria o melhor uso da interface. Da forma como está, dificulta a manutenção, pois eu tenho que mexer (como você disse) no contrato, depois na implementação concreta.

Comment: Além do que, eu penso que as vezes os principios mais dificultam do que ajudam. Não que eles sejam dispensáveis, longe disso, mas acho que devem ser melhores interpretados. As vezes seguir ao pé da letra padrões de projeto e/ou principios podem trazer mais burocracia do que agilidade.

Comment: Pois é @RicardoPontual pelo que entendi...e vai exatamente como eu penso, que o ponto central diz respeito a presença ou não de métodos, pois uma interface sem métodos não faz sentido pra mim. Acaba se tornando apenas burocracia. Obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: Só uma correção, a interface não pode ter campos, só métodos, e ela tem 32 métodos.

Comment: Classe `POCO`? Eu vim do Java, então esse nome me é novo. Tem alguma relação com o `POJO`?

Comment: @Maniero peraí... o que vc chama de campo são as Properties correto? Sendo assim nesse exemplo que usei a classe tem 16 propriedades (apenas leitura e escrita) ou seja são 16 campos. Não entendi o que vc quis dizer com ela tem 32 métodos.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado não sei o que seria POJO... rsrs Mas a POCO é uma classe que representa um objeto de maneira "pura", sem ter nenhuma dependência, podendo ser reaproveitada em diversos projetos. Aqui tem um link muito bom explicando: http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2012/10/classes-poco/

Comment: Campo, é campo, propriedade é propriedade. Interfaces não tem campos, só métodos. Propriedade é um conjunto métodos (pode ser apenas um, mas neste exemplo sempre tem 2) que pode ter um campo associado, mas na interface nunca tem. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89894/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática tb acho q se vc usar em todo lugar os princípios sem pensar se são bons ou não para cada situação atrapalha

Comment: sim @Maniero você está certo, usar interfaces em classes poco, entidade, dto, qualquer se seja o nome, e não tem operações não faz sentido

Comment: exatamente @Maniero, interfaces sem métodos não fazem sentido

Comment: O que estou dizendo é que esta interface tem 32 métodos. Até porque não existe interface sem métodos. E eles tem que ser públicos (talvez em C# 8 poderá ter métodos privados implementados na interface, mas é pra outra coisa). Leia os links. Então ela até faz sentido olhando por esse lado. Não faz sentido pela forma como o objeto que implementa ela será usado.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado sim sim, mesma coisa que POJO

Answer (score 8):

## Introdução

Eu tenho me preocupado muito com modelagem de software ultimamente. Tenho tentado melhorar meu entendimento sobre orientação a objetos para ir além do que as pessoas acham que este paradigma é, e que quase ninguém entende porque está usando. Tenho tentado aprender ferramentas novas, e ter uma visão aberta de como as coisas podem ajudar.

Mas mantenho minha filosofia básica de que ferramentas servem para te ajudar, não para atrapalhar. E se não dominá-las por completo não sabe se está ajudando ou atrapalhando.

A maioria das pessoas se apegam a certas ferramentas e ficam cegas com seu uso. Eu faço isto, todo mundo faz. Algumas pessoas fazem mais ou menos. Eu tento fazer menos.

Cada vez eu me convenço mais que praticamente toda modelagem atual, principalmente em aplicações de negócios, está errada. A forma feita não serve ao propósito do Agile, do OOP, do SOLID, DDD, e todas essas ferramentas que o povo propala ultimamente como solução para tudo.

## [SOLID](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178718/101)

Quase sempre vejo essa ideia de `Cliente`, `Fornecedor`, etc. sendo usada errado (Veja mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154748/101), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54177/101), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14839/101) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80948/101)). Quase sempre vejo [herança sendo usada errado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11378/101).

#### [S](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/101)

Facilidade de manutenção se dá mais pelo S do SOLID do que qualquer outra coisa. Ser capaz de [modularizar a aplicação é a coisa mais importante que tem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/223549/101). Ser capaz de fazer tudo ficar [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) é mais importante. Herança não costuma ajudar nisto, ela traz [acoplamento e baixa a coesão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101).

#### [O](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/236069/101)

As pessoas são ingênuas com relação ao O. A dificuldade de manutenção que o O provoca quando é feito errado é abismal. Na prática ele é útil mais quando se faz diferente do que as pessoas acreditam que seja herança. Quando faz herança praticamente se torna obrigatório fazer o O.

## [L](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101)

E se as pessoas entendessem o L provavelmente quase não fariam herança mais. Em domínios de negócios é muito raro dar certo. Mesmo herança de interface costuma dar errado.

Uma `Pessoa` é um objeto claro. `Cliente` pra mim só é um objeto claro se ele conter dados do papel de cliente. Se ele tiver dados da pessoa, pra mim esse objeto faz mais do que deveria. Então `Cliente` não pode derivar de `Pessoa`. Inclusive porque se `Fornecedor` fizer o mesmo, você terá possivelmente 2 objetos para a mesma pessoa, se alguém puder se cliente e fornecedor ao mesmo tempo.

Inclusive [se a modelagem for mais bem feita a impedância entre o modelo de objeto e o relacional fica menor ou inexistente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86715/101). Mas isto é outro assunto.

## [I](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191109/101)

Não esqueçamos do I. Ele não foi aplicado no exemplo da pergunta. O analista que ama tanto o SOLID esqueceu disto? Ou ele é do tipo que usa os termos de acordo com a sua vontade para mostrar que está certo fazer do jeito dele.

Tive um chefe assim. Ele citava um livro para dizer para "provar" que a opinião dele era certa. Quando eu citava o livro para argumentar com ele de algo que eu via como certo ele dizia que nem tudo do livro era para ser seguido. E eu concordo, só achava que eram os pontos diferentes do que ele achava. Então citar um livro ou um princípio não serve para nada se ele não encaixar na solução que você precisa.

Vamos dizer que resolva o I, será que aí ele vai querer colocar interface?

Vamos dizer que a interface correta é este. Isto dá pouca margem para composição, que é o que facilita a manutenção, apesar de complexar o *design*. [Para que criar uma interface que só serve a um tipo concreto? Isto me parece criar a interface por criar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30399/101).

## [D](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21319/101)

Usar interfaces no lugar de tipos concretos é ótimo. Inclusive ajuda no D do SOLID. Mas se abusar disto torna tudo mais complicado.

SOLID é bom quando aplicado onde precisa e do jeito que precisa.

#### Manutenção e *design complexo*

Como as pessoas conceituam errado, a manutenção fica prejudicada.

Quando não dá problema é porque o software era simples demais e não precisava tanto de manutenção quanto imaginavam e aí um *design* mais simples é melhor.

Vejo muito as pessoas fazendo softwares com *design* complexo porque facilita a manutenção e essa manutenção nunca acontece. E quando acontece o *design*  não ajuda tanto quanto a pessoa imaginava.

Precisa de muita experiência e muita cabeça aberta para começar fazer certo. E mesmo assim sempre vai errar.

Erra menos quem resolve sempre os mesmos problemas. Por isso acho que ainda erro muito.

Só que a pessoa que resolve sempre os mesmos problemas deve estar fazendo algo errado. Porque ainda não tem uma solução universal para os mesmos problemas?

Vejo muito software novo sendo feito quando já existe solução pronta. Vejo muito desenvolvedor fazendo trabalho repetitivo que é algo menos nobre para uma pessoa fazer. Tem programador que é quase um digitador.

## Interface

Sabe porque é bom ter essa interface?

Porque assim se um dia esse modelo estiver errado basta criar outro que atenda a mesma interface, assim terá um `BeneficiarioDtoV2` remodelado e que pode ser usado no lugar do `BeneficiarioDto` sem mexer no sistema e poder conviver com os dois.

É mesmo? Será que não precisará mexer no sistema de verdade? Será que o modelo não causará diversas implicações por todo o sistema? Será que a própria interface não precisará ser remodelada?

Se tiver que mexer na interface toda vez que mexer no tipo concreto está fazendo o oposto do que prega o SOLID. Tudo que pode ser herdado ou implementado em derivativos não pode mais mexer depois de criar, é o O.

O motivo de existir uma interface é dar aos consumidores a capacidade de acessar um comportamento específico de um objeto e mais que isto, não é dar acesso a todo comportamento do objeto, para isto existe o tipo concreto. A interface tem que ser pensada em como os consumidores se beneficiação dela, e não como o tipo que a implementa se beneficiará.

O exemplo da pergunta me parece um caso de tentar usar interfaces para tudo. E pior, nem ele acredita nisso, porque tem coisas que ele prefere não usar interface, como pode ser visto no modelo. Então fica quase aleatório, é de acordo com o gosto dele.

Pode-se questionar o uso de DTO. Muita gente diz que isto é errado. Não vou entrar no mérito. Mas já que ele existe, não consigo ver a vantagem da interface aí, a não ser para fazer gambiarra. Também tem quem misture a regra de negócio do objeto com o mecanismo dele. Cada vez mais acho isto errado e acho que a maioria das pessoas não consegue diferenciar um do outro, mas isso é outro assunto.

Me parece que a interface está sendo colocada "por via das dúvidas" em algo que dificilmente será necessário. Este objeto deve ser consumido em lugar muito específico.

## *Design* perfeito

Se abstrair tudo perfeitamente realmente não terá consequências extras na manutenção. Mas nunca vi algo que está perfeitamente abstraído. vejo casos graves de abstração, como o citado do `Cliente` ser uma `Pessoa` para a maioria dos modelos por aí. Com abstrações erradas de nada adianta usar essas técnicas.

Sempre tem soluções que podem ser feitas posteriormente. Se ficarão boas é outras estória. Dar antes soluções desnecessárias é tão ruim quanto não dar antes soluções necessárias.

Por causa do SOLID e outras técnicas vejo *designs* desastrosos por aí. Ou porque não precisa dele ou porque fazem tudo errado. A pessoa acredita que entende como aplicar algo e que é só aplicar que tudo ficará maravilhoso. Ambas são presunções bem equivocadas geralmente pelo [efeito Dunning-Kruger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect).

Pra falar a verdade não tem solução fácil e que seja garantidamente 100% correta.

## Seu projeto e seu problema

Se é o mais adequado para este projeto eu não sei porque não conheço ele como um todo. E aprendi que a maioria das pessoas erram porque fazem projetos sem conhecer o todo. Quase todos os projetos são assim. Tem um jeito que "acharam" para garantir que tudo será fácil de dar manutenção que é abstrair tudo. Só que a pessoa fica com dois problemas. Porque ela nunca abstrai tudo como deveria e sempre vai ter abstrações erradas que vão dificultar a manutenção e terá um sistema complexo demais e que a maioria dos pontos nunca precisará de manutenção. Pelo menos não naquilo que foi previsto.

Então não argumente, questione. Faça ele provar que é necessário. É provável que não funcione. Mas aí seu argumento é que ele não argumentou porque deve fazer algo. Tudo que vai fazer deve ser bem argumentado. Tem que saber porque está fazendo. Dizer que é para seguir o SOLID não é argumento plausível. Tem que mostrar porque isto será um benefício **real** para o projeto.

Pode ser que não consiga refutar os argumentos dele. Aí é algo que ainda não desenvolveu, ou você está errado. Não podemos ajudar nisso, a única solução seria a gente ir lá debater com ele e não você.

Claro que sempre poderá haver um impasse. Ele pode dizer qualquer bobagem e você ter que aceitar. Ele pode dizer algo concreto e útil e você não entender. Isto faz parte de relações humanas. Aí o problema é outro e não podemos ajudar.

Tá aí alguns subsídios para pensar, se questionar, questionar ele, formar sua opinião com um pouco mais de base e argumentar com ele. Continue perguntando, estudando, vendo outros pontos de vista.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Maniero. Vc disse algo que é um ponto chave do que penso: "Vejo muito as pessoas fazendo softwares com design complexo porque facilita a manutenção e essa manutenção nunca acontece. E quando acontece o design não ajuda tanto quanto a pessoa imaginava."  É justamente meu medo. Pois este processo tem emperrado muito o desenvolvimento, sempre com a desculpa de que a manutenção será SUPER fácil. mas vai mesmo ter essa manutenção algum dia?

Comment: Estava lendo sua resposta, ótimos pontos, só em relação a versionar o DTO que acho estranho.. nunca fiz isso, na verdade, versiono todo o projeto de modelo com todas as entidades/dtos, acho mais prático.

Comment: o que você comentou sobre as ferramentas é uma verdade. temos que cuidar para não ficar extremistas. eu entendo que às vezes o arquiteto faz isso para evitar "brechas" e que as pessoas fujam dos princípios, patterns, ferramentas, etc, mas isso pode ser um problema, você pode não analisar a melhor maneira de resolver problemas específicos

Comment: Coloquei como gambiarra, não como prática comum, não precisa fazer isto, mas a interface serve pra isso

Comment: @AlamBique isso acontece comigo, onde trabalho, em mais de um projeto... temos sistemas inteiros baseados em interface, gerados por template claro para facilitar, mas q na maioria das camadas **nunca** foram usando inversão de dependêcia, testes e mocks, fazendo só com q tenhamos muito código, muita coisa alinhada com padrões, mas nenhuma prática de uso