# Como eu sei que minha função está quebrando o SOLID de POO?

Tags: node.js, orientação-a-objetos, solid

Deixei uma função abaixo que será alvo da pergunta, basicamente eu gostaria de saber se essa função quebra algum principio do SOLID/Clean Code por si só ? Essa dúvida surgiu pois tecnicamente ela faz 2 coisas que seriam buscar um saldo no banco de dados e validar o retorno.

```
    public buscarSaldo = async (): Promise<boolean> => {
    const requerentes = await this.db.getAccount(this.agencia, this.bco, this.conta)
    if(typeof requerentes == "boolean")
    {
        return false;
    }else{
        this.saldo = requerentes[0].SALDO
        return true;   
    }
}
```

Sei que parece algo bobo, mas como posso saber se minha função está quebrando algum principio que a faz com o código "feio" ? Existe algum macete para isso ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Estudando muito, mas muito mesmo. Esse é o "macete". Essas coisas são tidas como receitas de bolo por muitos e é só seguir que tudo dará certo, mas não é bem assim. As pessoas fazem errado o tempo todo porque não se aprofundam, não entendem as reais motivações, então muitas vezes até adotar o [SOLID](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178718/101) já pode ser um erro. Ou adotar OOP também pode ser um erro.

É comum as pessoas sequer entenderam o que essas coisas significam de verdade, o porquê de estarem usando todos os conceitos por trás daquilo. Usam porque está na moda. Nenhum motivo técnico. Claro, essas ferramentas podem ser úteis em certos cenários, mas só será quando a pessoa domina o que está fazendo, o que demanda muita dedicação e muito tempo de experiência porque só o erro ensina de fato como tomar boas decisões de arquitetura e engenharia (não estou desconsiderando o profundo estudo, como já disse antes).

Tenho 30 anos de programação orientada a objeto, estudo muito o assunto e ainda cometo erros nos casos concretos. Por que alguém que está começando agora acha que pode só ver o assunto por cima e repetir sempre a mesma coisa e ainda acertar? Coisas do ser humano...

Se você está perguntando se uma função quebra o SOLID, minha recomendação é ver do que se trata a ideia dela, porque uma função não indica muita coisa sobre isso. E mais, sem saber os requisitos não tem como fazer essa análise. Me parece que você está tão preocupado com a técnica específica que está esquecendo do fundamento, que é o que importa de fato. Inclusive porque co9m ele pode tomar suas próprias decisões e se tornar um profissional com P maiúsculo.

Você dá a ideia que quer saber se está violando o S do SOLID. Não posso afirmar sem saber os detalhes do que está fazendo. Me parece que está usando coisas que não precisam aí, talvez porque é *cool* fazer assim (duvido que seja por necessidade, mas posso estar enganado, como eu disse, não tenho os detalhes). Eu faria ela de uma forma bem diferente, e parece violar o princípio da responsabilidade única sim.

Tente fazer isso separando a busca da validação. Veja se ficou melhor. Duvido, aí você verá que talvez o SOLID manda você fazer coisas que pioram seu código e é melhor saber que ele existe, dominá-lo para aplicar quando for útil, mas se preocupar mais em fazer código melhor que resolve o problema da melhor forma, sem se preocupar se é SOLID, OOP, ou outra coisa.

Eu nem tentaria aplicar algo que eu não domino por completo, porque senão farei errado com certeza.

Comment: No caso eu estou apenas tentando aprender mesmo... Acho que aprendo melhor fazendo código e vendo por mim mesmo a diferença da utilização ou não da técnica, achei bem interessante sua colocação "talvez o SOLID manda você fazer coisas que pioram seu código", por enquanto sou apenas uma pessoa tentando aprender essas técnicas e princípios para começar a poder tomar decisões melhores a cerca de escrita de código, estou tentando aprender o que significa tudo isso antes de colocar em prática