# Como funciona na teoria o padrão de projeto Composite?

Tags: java, design-pattern, engenharia-de-software

Como funciona na teoria esse padrão? Que tipo de problema ele resolve e quais as utilidades ele trás ou algo assim?

Comment: Uma boa pesquisa responde a sua dúvida. Verifique este site: https://robsoncastilho.com.br/2013/07/10/design-patterns-usando-composite-para-montar-uma-estrutura-em-arvore/

Comment: Veja se este post te ajuda -> https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É um destes padrões para problemas bem específicos e que se usado onde não deve só cria complexidade sem dar benefício real. Grande parte das vezes é possível fazer algo mais simples. Uma das dificuldades de entender é porque ele sempre é mostrado com um modelo de objetos que na prática não deveria ser formados daquela forma em bom código. Todos os exemplos que eu vi são ruins e fazem herança onde não deve, então até questiono sua validade, não porque garanto que seja inválido, mas porque está mal definido no material fácil de achar (um copia do outro só para gerar conteúdo sem preocupação em explicar de forma mais adequada), pode ser só que todos estejam errados porque um entendeu errado e todos foram na onda. Este é um dos motivos que não ligo para *design patterns*, eu tenho um problema e procuro uma boa solução para resolver, muitos deles são obviedades quando a pessoa sabe programar.

O objetivo dele é criar uma hierarquia de objetos com características semelhantes. O que dá essa semelhança é uma interface que passa ser considerada como um componente do objeto. Pense nela como um lista de dados especializada onde todos elementos possuem a implementação necessária para fazer alguma coisa determinada por um tipo (uma interface). Seria algo como um `List<Printable>`, mas não é só uma lista, pode criar uma árvore de objetos assim, e esta lista possui a os recursos (métodos) de lidar com essa capacidade (no exemplo é capaz de imprimir algo) diretamente por ela e não precisa chamar o elemento da hierarquia de forma direta, e ainda existe uma forma de adicionar ou retirar objetos nesta hierarquia como em qualquer coleção de dados.

Algumas pessoas até criticam porque ele seria incompleto e não provê partes que seriam interessantes em toda coleção de dados desta forma. Alguns dizem que os mecanismos que administrem a entrada e retirada de um novo objeto na hierarquia devem estar nesta interface definida para agrupar os objetos. Eu acho que isto viola o I do [SOLID](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178718/101) (não que eu acho que violar algum princípio seja proibido, mas as pessoas que criam essas coisas não gostam que viole).

É uma boa abstração, mas não tem nada de muito especial nisto, e talvez por ser um pouco falha seja pouco usada, pelo menos de forma clara. Até acredito que as pessoas façam coisas parecidas onde precisa e nem se dão conta, o que de certa forma pode ser o melhor padrão de projeto, aquele que você usa sem perceber. Parece estar (não que seja) mais para uma estrutura de dados do que um DP.

[image: Diagrama do Composite]

Note que com a evolução de algumas linguagens nem sei se isto deveria ser feito desta forma.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).