# Implementar somente métodos diretos de uma interface

Tags: java, interface

Digamos que eu tenha a interface `Vehicle`:

```
public interface Vehicle {
    void moveForward();
    void moveBackward();
    void moveLeft();
    void moveRight();
}
```

E a interface `LandVehicle`:

```
public interface LandVehicle extends Vehicle{
    void repairTire();
}
```

Se eu tiver uma classe, digamos, Carro, é possível que eu faça somente a implementação dos métodos da interface `LandVehicle`? Tendo uma implementação padrão de Vehicle, em outra classe?

Pois cada veiculo terrestre terá sua própria execução do método `repairTire()`, mas todos terão a mesma execução dos métodos utilizados para locomoção da interface Vehicle.

A minha pretensão é fazer uma abstração dos métodos utilizados para o banco de dados, para que caso um dia seja necessário posso trocar o banco de dados sem precisar de refactor nas classes que já utilizavam esses métodos.
Me baseei na interface `CrudRepository` do Spring (Não posso utilizar spring nesse projeto). Teria por exemplo:

UsuarioRepository <- MongoRespository <- CrudRepository

Comment: Há algum motivo para não se usar métodos default na interface ou então usar transformar a interface numa superclasse? Se sim qual?

Comment: Seu problema me lembra isso: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> é possível que eu faça somente a implementação dos métodos da interface `LandVehicle`?

Não é possível, você tem que implementar tudo, em algum lugar. Nem faria sentido permitir isso. Uma interface é um contrato, quando resolve por ela na sua classe significa que quer cumprir todo o contrato que ela exige. Se não quer fazer isso então não quer se conformar com essa interface.

Pode ser que as interfaces foram mal pensadas e queria montar de outra forma, pode ser que esteja faltando segregação maior às interfaces e ter nelas só o que importa para cada uma dessas interfaces, então está misturando responsabilidades. Se tiver a separação correta poderia escolher a interface certa para se conformar e não ganhar comportamentos indesejados no objeto. Então a herança ali está errada. Vai violando um [princípio SOLID](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178718/101) atrás do outro sem um motivo plausível.

> Tendo uma implementação padrão de `Vehicle`, em outra classe?

O código não mostra uma implementação padrão. Se tiver uma então toda vez que for acessar essa implementação padrão será usada e aí não precisa implementar de novo, mas não é que não precisa implementar, já está implementada.

Comment: Pode ser que o AP esteja pensando em criar uma classe que implementa `Vehicle` e implementa cada um dos métodos da interface, e criar uma subclasse que implementa `LandVehicle`, aí não precisaria implementar os que já foram implementados.

Comment: Pode ser, mas precisaria ficar mais claro. De qualquer forma vale o mesmo que eu disse para a interface já implementar., o que já está implementado não precisa implementar de novo, e aí não tem problema algum.

Comment: @Piovezan Era exatamente isso, não tinha pensado dessa forma. Uma classe que implementa Vehicle e uma classe que extende essa implementação e também implementa os métodos de LandVehicle.

Comment: E está parecendo realmente um problema XY