# Comando update não funciona

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, oracle11g

Tenho três tabelas em um banco de dados, e tenho um método chamado `alteraLinhaTabela` em que tento atualizar uma das três tabelas por vez identificando-a pela variável `tabela`. Também passo mais duas classes que contém o conteúdo da atualização, mas para cada tabela uma classe diferente, uma vai ser `null` enquanto a outra não.

Ignorado o `if (tabela == 1) {...}`, tenho um segundo `if` em que escolhe a instrução SQL a ser executada para cada tabela. Crio o `PreparedStatement` e seto as variáveis de uma das classes (essa "setagem" acontece no método `dadosDasLinhas`, que uso também em outros métodos), executo, e fecho o `PreparedStatement`.

```
public void alteraLinhaTabela(int tabela, Tabela1 t1, Tabela2 t2) {

    String query = "";

    try {

        if (tabela == 1) {

            if (t1.getPagamentoTotal() == 0) {

                deleteLinha(t1.getId(), 1);

                tabela = 3;

                insereLinhaTabela(tabela, t1, t2);

                return;

            }

        }

        if (tabela == 1 || tabela == 3)
            query = "update tabela" + tabela + " set nome=?, dataPagamento=?, atrazo=?, pagamentoTotal=? where id=?";
        else if (tabela == 2)
            query = "update tabela" + tabela + " set endereco=?, telefone=?, cpf=?, produto=?, valorProduto=? where id=?";

        PreparedStatement stmt = getConexao().prepareStatement(query);

        dadosDasLinhas(stmt, tabela, t1, t2);

        if (tabela == 1) 
            stmt.setInt(5, t1.getId());
         else if (tabela == 2) 
            stmt.setInt(6, t2.getId());

        stmt.execute();

        stmt.close();   

    } catch(SQLException e) {

        throw new RuntimeException(e);

    }

}

private void dadosDasLinhas(PreparedStatement stmt, int tabela, Tabela1 t1, Tabela2 t2) {

    try {

        if (tabela == 1) {

            stmt.setString(1, t1.getNome());
            stmt.setString(2, t1.getDataPagamento());
            stmt.setInt(3, t1.getAtrazo());
            stmt.setDouble(4, t1.getPagamentoTotal());

        } else if (tabela == 2) {

            stmt.setString(1, t2.getEndereco());
            stmt.setString(2, t2.getTelefone());
            stmt.setString(3, t2.getCpf());
            stmt.setString(4, t2.getProduto().toString().replace(" ", "")//retira espaços
                    .replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));//retira cochetes
            stmt.setString(5, t2.getValorProduto().toString().replace(" ", "")//retira espaços
                    .replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));//retira cochetes

        }

    } catch(SQLException e) {

        throw new RuntimeException(e);

    }

}
```

Considerando que eu só quero atualizar a primeira tabela (que tem as colunas nome, dataPagamento, atrazo e pagamento), se tenho uma linha com:

> nome = Fulano dos Testes,
>   dataPagamento = 2017-03-07,
>   atrazo = 5,
>   pagamento = 1450;

Altero somente o atrazo e executo o método `alteraLinhaTabela`.

Mas quando faço um `SELECT` vejo que não alterou nada. Se vejo o console, está em branco. Se tento pela linha de comando funciona. Se procuro um erro na instrução SQL, não encontro. Se vejo a conexão com o banco de dados, está tudo certo (e até insere linhas). Se faço um debug, vejo que ele passa por todas as linhas e não apresenta nenhum erro ou falta de dados em qualquer variável.

Fiquei sem ideias do que pode estar acontecendo.

O banco de dados é o Oracle Database 11g Express Edition. A IDE é o Eclipse.

Comment: O que há no seu método `getConexao()`? Estou com uma resposta escrita pela metade, mas não consigo terminá-la sem saber como este método está implementado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Acoplamento de controle

Antes de responder a sua dúvida diretamente, permita-me falar um pouco sobre o acoplamento de controle.

Se você tem um método que tem um parâmetro que denota o que ele tem que fazer e lá dentro você tem um `if` ou um `switch` que com base neste parâmetro decide o comportamento desejado, ainda mais quando um tipo de comportamento tem pouca ou nenhuma relação com um outro tipo de comportamento, **é porque deveriam ser métodos separados**. Isso daí é um exemplo de [acoplamento de controle](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/81337/132).

O acomplamento de controle fica ainda pior quando alguns dos parâmetros servem só para alguns dos comportamentos enquanto os outros servem para outros comportamentos, mas todos eles estão na mesma assinatura de método. Um exemplo de um caso grave de acoplamento de controle seria isso:

```
public String desenharCirculoOuEscreverXML(int oQueFazer, Graphics g, Produto p) {
    if (oQueFazer == 1) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawEllipse(20, 20, 50, 50);
    } else if (oQueFazer == 2) {
        return "<produto><nome>" + p.getNome() + "</nome><codigo>" + p.getCodigo() + "</codigo></produto>";
    }
    return null;
}
```

Observe que este método abriga e mistura duas funcionalidades completamente diferentes que não tem sentido de estarem juntas, o que resulta em código confuso, espaguete, amarrado, gambiarrado, difícil de se usar e difícil de se alterar. Tudo ficaria muito mais fácil se elas fossem separadas:

```
public void desenharCirculo(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawEllipse(20, 20, 50, 50);
}

public String escreverXML(Produto p) {
    return "<produto><nome>" + p.getNome() + "</nome><codigo>" + p.getCodigo() + "</codigo></produto>";
}
```

## Removendo o acomplamento de controle

Pois bem, o seu código tem um sério problema de acoplamento de controle, tanto no método `alteraLinhaTabela` quanto no método `dadosDasLinhas`. Para tanto, vamos primeiro separar as funcionalidades que estão misturadas:

```
public void alteraLinhaTabela1(Tabela1 t1) {
    if (t1.getPagamentoTotal() == 0) {
        deleteLinha(t1.getId(), 1);
        insereLinhaTabela3(t1);
        return;    
    }

    try {
        String query = "update tabela1 set nome=?, dataPagamento=?, atrazo=?, pagamentoTotal=? where id=?";

        PreparedStatement stmt = getConexao().prepareStatement(query);

        dadosDasLinhas1(stmt, t1);

        stmt.setInt(5, t1.getId());
        stmt.execute();
        stmt.close();   
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public void alteraLinhaTabela2(Tabela2 t2) {
    try {
        String query = "update tabela2 set endereco=?, telefone=?, cpf=?, produto=?, valorProduto=? where id=?";

        PreparedStatement stmt = getConexao().prepareStatement(query);

        dadosDasLinhas2(stmt, t2);

        stmt.setInt(6, t2.getId());
        stmt.execute();
        stmt.close();   
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private void dadosDasLinhas1(PreparedStatement stmt, Tabela1 t1) {
    try {
        stmt.setString(1, t1.getNome());
        stmt.setString(2, t1.getDataPagamento());
        stmt.setInt(3, t1.getAtrazo());
        stmt.setDouble(4, t1.getPagamentoTotal());
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private void dadosDasLinhas2(PreparedStatement stmt, Tabela2 t2) {
    try {
        stmt.setString(1, t2.getEndereco());
        stmt.setString(2, t2.getTelefone());
        stmt.setString(3, t2.getCpf());
        stmt.setString(4, t2.getProduto().toString().replace(" ", "")//retira espaços
                .replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));//retira cochetes
        stmt.setString(5, t2.getValorProduto().toString().replace(" ", "")//retira espaços
                .replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));//retira cochetes
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

## Responsabilidade das classes

Acho que é um tanto óbvio que a funcionalidade que fornece o nome de um `Produto` deveria estar na classe `Produto`. Também é óbvio que esse nome deveria, se possível, vir adequadamente formatado para que outras classes não precisem ficar consertando-o. Entretanto, não é isso que o seu código mostra:

```
        stmt.setString(4, t2.getProduto().toString().replace(" ", "")//retira espaços
                .replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));//retira cochetes
        stmt.setString(5, t2.getValorProduto().toString().replace(" ", "")//retira espaços
                .replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));//retira cochetes
```

Isso indica que a classe `Produto` não fornece o seu nome em um formato correto, o que obriga outras classes a terem que consertá-lo. Ora, isso significa que a classe `Produto` não está fazendo a sua parte direito e que portanto outras classes acabam tendo que arrumar/consertar/corrigir aquilo que esta classe não está sabendo fazer direito mas que deveria saber, o que é uma gambiarra. Assim sendo, o ideal é que a classe `Produto` disponibilize um método que forneça o nome no formato correto. O mesmo pode ser dito sobre o valor do produto na classe `Tabela2`.

Aliás, isso tem tudo a ver com o [princípio da inversão de dependência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101552/132) - O seu código está dependendo de detalhes do comportamento dos métodos, e não apenas em chamar os métodos. Desse princípio também pode ser inferida a regra *não fale com estranhos* - ou seja, o método não deve chamar outros métodos que não sejam de objetos diretamente relacionados. A melhor alternativa então seria colocar isso na classe `Produto`:

```
public String getNomeLimpo() {
    return toString().replace(" ", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
}
```

E isso na classe `Tabela2`:

```
public String getNomeLimpoProduto() {
    return getProduto().getNomeLimpo();
}

public String getValorLimpoProduto() {
    return getValorProduto().toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
}
```

E com isso, no método `dadosDasLinhas2` temos:

```
        stmt.setString(4, t2.getNomeLimpoProduto());
        stmt.setString(5, t2.getValorLimpoProduto());
```

## Segurança ao usar o `PreparedStatement`

O seu código não lida com o `PreparedStatement` adequadamente. Em especial, se o código lançar uma exceção, o `PreparedStatement` poderá permanecer aberto em um estado zumbi, assim como a conexão também. A forma ideal de lidar com este problema é usar o [*try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132).

Aliás, não só o `PreparedStatement`, como a `Connection` também deve estar em um estado zumbi, uma vez que você não a finaliza e nem executa o commit. A conexão deve estar em modo auto-commit (e portanto o `commit` explícito é desnecessário), mas mesmo assim, ela deve ser adequadamente fechada. **Esta deve ser a falha que você está relatando** que faz com que nada apareça no banco de dados.

Também podemos mover as SQLs para campos estáticos.

```
private static final String ALTERA_LINHA_TABELA1_SQL =
    "UPDATE tabela1 SET nome = ?, dataPagamento = ?, atrazo = ?, pagamentoTotal = ? WHERE id = ?";

private static final String ALTERA_LINHA_TABELA2_SQL =
    "UPDATE tabela2 SET endereco = ?, telefone = ?, cpf = ?, produto = ?, valorProduto = ? where id = ?";

public void alteraLinhaTabela1(Tabela1 t1) {
    if (t1.getPagamentoTotal() == 0) {
        deleteLinha(t1.getId(), 1);
        insereLinhaTabela3(t1);
        return;    
    }

    try (
        Connection c = getConexao();
        PreparedStatement stmt = c.prepareStatement(ALTERA_LINHA_TABELA1_SQL);
    ) {
        dadosDasLinhas1(stmt, t1);
        stmt.setInt(5, t1.getId());
        stmt.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public void alteraLinhaTabela2(Tabela2 t2) {
    try (
        Connection c = getConexao();
        PreparedStatement stmt = c.prepareStatement(ALTERA_LINHA_TABELA1_SQL);
    ) {
        dadosDasLinhas2(stmt, t2);
        stmt.setInt(6, t2.getId());
        stmt.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private void dadosDasLinhas1(PreparedStatement stmt, Tabela1 t1) throws SQLException {
    stmt.setString(1, t1.getNome());
    stmt.setString(2, t1.getDataPagamento());
    stmt.setInt(3, t1.getAtrazo());
    stmt.setDouble(4, t1.getPagamentoTotal());
}

private void dadosDasLinhas2(PreparedStatement stmt, Tabela2 t2) throws SQLException {
    stmt.setString(1, t2.getEndereco());
    stmt.setString(2, t2.getTelefone());
    stmt.setString(3, t2.getCpf());
    stmt.setString(4, t2.getNomeLimpoProduto());
    stmt.setString(5, t2.getValorLimpoProduto());
}
```

## Gerenciamento de conexões

Eu parti da suposição que o seu método `getConexao()` devolva uma conexão recém-aberta, no modo autocommit (que é o padrão) e que deveria ser fechada em seguida após ser utilizada (conecta, faz alguma coisa, desconecta). **Recomendo fortemente que faça isso caso não esteja fazendo.**

Se não for este o caso e você quiser insistir em reutilizar uma conexão, então o início dos blocos `try` seria assim:

```
try (PreparedStatement stmt = getConexao().prepareStatement(ALTERA_LINHA_TABELA1_SQL)) {
```

Entretanto, lidar adequadamente com conexões já abertas anteriormente não é algo muito fácil de se fazer. A única coisa que é fácil nesse caso é a possibilidade de se fazer besteira. Vendo o nível de maturidade do resto do seu código, duvido que você tenha conexões reutilizáveis implementadas de forma correta, pois se estivesse não estaria tendo o problema que está tendo (desculpe-me a sinceridade).

Caso você fosse utilizar conexões já abertas anteriormente no seu método `getConexao()`, você provavelmente vai querer ter transações bem delimitadas, e com isso teria o auto-commit desabilitado e o `commit()` e o `rollback()` explícitos em algum lugar do seu código. Além disso, você teria que se preocupar em delimitar o escopo da transação, que normalmente corresponde a uma requisição no caso de um sistema web ou de uma *action* no caso de um sistema desktop. Com isso, para lidar corretamente com esses conceitos, você tem que saber lidar com `ThreadLocal`s e limpar a conexão caso a thread em questão puder ser reutilizada (caso típico de aplicações web). Um outro problema além disso e mais complicado seria lidar com conexões em pool.

Assim sendo, recomendo que o seu método `getConexao()` devolva conexões que tenham acabado de ser abertas, com o autocommit habilitado e que sejam sempre utilizadas com o *try-with-resources* para garantir o fechamento adequado. Sugiro tentar um gerenciamento de conexões mais complexo apenas quando você já for um Cavaleiro Jedi no Java, porque isso não é coisa para padawans.

## Outras possíveis melhorias

Provavelmente há mais melhorias que seriam possíveis, mas isso depende de mais informações sobre o seu projeto que não estão na sua pergunta. Em especial acredito que melhorias ainda cabem nas seguintes áreas:

- Atraso se escreve com "s", e não com "z"!
- O valor do produto deveria ser algo vindo de dentro do produto e não de `Tabela2`.
- O fato de `Produto` e `ValorProduto` terem métodos `toString()` que produzem resultados que necessitam ser consertados depois é um tanto suspeito.
- Não acho que o `if (t1.getPagamentoTotal() == 0) { ... }` esteja no lugar mais adequado.
- Utilizar `catch (SQLException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }` provavelmente não é uma boa forma de se tratar erros.

Comment: Era esse o motivo de não funcionar, eu fiquei modificando várias classes que tinham esse acoplamento até chegar na classe em que faço a edição, e então percebi que estava fazendo isso, essa classe eu utilizo como Controller de um .fxml(javafx) que serve para inserir dados, então eu pensei em colocar para alterar dados também(já que ia praticamente duplicar a classe e o .fxml se fizesse separadamente), mas eu me esqueci de mudar a id que ficou igual a -1. Eu pensava que se eu colocasse para alterar, inserir, etc. todas as tabelas em um mesmo método ficaria melhor, mas só fez piorar o código.

Comment: A sua resposta me mostrou também que eu ainda tenho muito o que melhorar, pensava eu que já era um bom programador. Mas esse meu erro de português é injustificável(Como eu errei isso?).