# duvida classe genérica asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, mvc, interface, genéricos, repository

Boa noite,

No meu projeto tenho uma camada de aplicação onde a classe está estruturada da seguinte forma:

> ```
> namespace ProjetoTreino.Aplicacao {
> public class PessoaAplicacao 
> {
>     private readonly IRepositorio<Pessoa> repositorio;
>
>     public PessoaAplicacao(IRepositorio<Pessoa> rep)
>     {
>         repositorio = rep;
>     }
>
>     public void Excluir(Pessoa entidade)
>     {
>         repositorio.Excluir(entidade);
>     }
>
>     public void Inserir(Pessoa entidade)
>     {
>         repositorio.Inserir(entidade);
>     }
>
>     public Pessoa ListarPorId(int id)
>     {
>         return repositorio.ListarPorId(id);
>     }
>
>     public IEnumerable<Pessoa> ListarTodos()
>     {
>         return repositorio.ListarTodos();
>     }
>
>     public void Update(Pessoa entidade)
>     {
>         repositorio.Update(entidade);
>     }
> } }
> ```

Queria saber se está realmente certo declarar essa propriedade e esse construtor dessa forma ou se eu deveria em vez de declarar IRepositorio pegar o Repositorio direto ja que o Repositorio herda de IRepositorio, e tambem se eu poderia em vez de declarar a propriedade ja herdar dela como no exemplo:

```
public class PessoaAplicacao : Repositorio<Pessoa>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Queria saber se está realmente certo declarar essa propriedade e esse
>   construtor dessa forma ou se eu deveria em vez de declarar
>   IRepositorio pegar o Repositorio direto ja que o Repositorio herda de
>   IRepositorio.

Você poderia sim instanciar diretamente o Repositorio. Porém, normalmente seguindo o padrão DIP, é recomendável utilizar essa forma que você exemplifica.

- [O que é "Princípio da Inversão de Dependência" (DIP)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101552/o-que-%C3%A9-princ%C3%ADpio-da-invers%C3%A3o-de-depend%C3%AAncia-dip)

Ainda vale citar que é provável que exista um componente de injeção de dependencia por traz disso que necessita da interface para funcionar corretamente.

> e tambem se eu poderia em vez de declarar a propriedade ja herdar dela
>   como no exemplo:

Não, no seu exemplo você esta dizendo que PessoaAplicacao possui uma implementação de IRepositorio como uma propriedade, já que não é obrigação da aplicação de persistir dados. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso você faça `public class PessoaAplicacao : Repositorio<Pessoa>`, esta dizendo que PessoaAplicacao é filho de Repositorio, logo ele possui todas as características de Repositorio e passa ser responsável por persistir os dados. Veja que existe diferença.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A modelagem ficou bem simples e pode haver problemas, feedback da comunidade é sempre bem vindo.

Comment: Não seria o caso de herdar a interface?

Comment: Não entendi, herdar a interface?

Comment: mas em vez de eu declarar uma propriedade private readonly IRepositorio<Pessoa> repositorio; assim, buscando de IRepositorio, nao poderia bsucar direto de Repositorio, ao inves da interface ?

Comment: A referência é IRepositorio, mas na verdade por trás existe um componente que vai estar fazendo um new Repositorio<Pessoa>(). ele não vai estar "buscando" de IRepositorio.